# MySQL:values are not correctly imported from yyyymmdd to date variable, using str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date, csv, import, str-to-date

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(`ID` INT NULL,  
`DATE` DATE NULL,   
`NUM` INT NULL
); 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "fakepath/file.csv"
    INTO TABLE A
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (ID,DATE,NUM)
    SET
    DATE = str_to_date(@DATE, '%Y%m%d');
```

The original data in csv file is like this-- 20160101,20160102,20160103 (the date is different). After I execute the code, **all the date** in the DATE column become one day value such as 2016-01-02 in table A.

Why do this happen? I have other table which used the same code(different column name)

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell MySQL to load the from-csv data value into a variable first:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "fakepath/file.csv"
    [..snip..]
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (ID,DATE,NUM)
         ^---table field, **NOT** a variable
    SET
    DATE = str_to_date(@DATE, '%Y%m%d');
                          ^---variable never gets populated
```

Try

```
(ID, @DATE, NUM)
     ^--note this
```

instead. That'll load the id/num values directly into the table, but puts your date value into the variable, which you can use afterwards in the `SET` portion of the query.

The fact that you actually get a date value put into the table with a proper date format indicates that somwhere else, in previous code, you did set a `@DATE` variable, and it's simply being re-used in this query. But since you don't CHANGE that variable's value in this query, you end up using the SAME date value for all records.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right! I did forget to add "@" for this query. Problem solved